# In a Qt application under Windows, the wrong button is selected by default

Tags: windows, qt4.7

I've been developing a desktop application using Qt Creator under Linux (Kubuntu).
Under linux, all is well, but under Windows, in a dialog box, the wrong button is selected by default when the window appears.

There are three buttons: Edit, Continue and Stop.

Continue is marked as 'AutoDefault' and 'Default'.

Stop is marked as 'AutoDefault', but not 'Deafault'.

Edit is marked as neither 'AutoDefault' nor 'Default', but when the dialog opens, it is selected, and pressing enter presses the Edit button.

The source for the program can be found at https://github.com/megamasha/FlashKard for anyone who wants to try it themselves. The window in question is generated from the 'resultswindow.ui' file.

Is this just me? Is this a bug? Just wondering if anyone can see any obvious reason why this doesn't work (or perhaps it just doesn't work on my Windows Vista system)

Comment: @pezcode: Sorry, silly omission. The window is generated from reultswindow.ui. Other code is in the .h and .cpp files of the same name. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `QPushButton::default`:

> A button with this property set to true (i.e., the dialog's default
>   button,) will automatically be pressed when the user presses enter,
>   with one exception: if an autoDefault button currently has focus, the
>   autoDefault button is pressed.

And more importantly:

> Command buttons in dialogs are by default auto-default buttons, i.e.
>   they become the default push button automatically when they receive
>   the keyboard input focus.

Unless you explicitly set `editButton`'s *autoDefault* to false, it is true. There might be some Windows specifics involved (without further hints, Windows focuses the control with the lowest ID, which is probably the case for `editButton`, since it's created first).
Try either setting *autoDefault* to false, or explicitly call `continueButton.setFocus()`

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried setting the others to AutoDefault=false, without success. Interestingly, I even moved the buttons around in QtDesigner, so that The continue button was on the left, and you know what changed? Nothing. I re-built. Still nothing - the Edit button remained on the far left, and selected by default. Very curious. Will reboot into Windows now and try calling setFocus() explicitly.

Comment: OK, well the good news is, calling `ui->continueButton->setFocus()` works as to be expected. It's still weird though that Windows seems to ignore defaults and the order in which the buttons are arranged in Qt Designer. I'd be interested to know if you get the same results if you try moving them around in Designer. Perhaps this is a bug that should be reported (or at least mentioned in the documentation)?

Comment: Well, that's weird. I opened the .ui in Qt Creator and editButton had autoDefault set to true. I unchecked, saved, compiled and it works as expected (Continue gets the focus). Maybe try a recent Qt Creator version, I used 2.4.1 with Qt 4.7.4

Comment: Weird... Not sure what's going on there. The whole idea of the buttons (even their order) not changing when I change the .ui file suggests that it's not being recompiled, which could be why it's not working as expected.
Perhaps I'll try a newer version of Qt. Or reinstalling Qt. Whatever it is, at least I have a workaround. And from a personal viewpoint, I'm not affected, as I don't use Windows.